# How to concatenate parts of strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I have to print out an account username which will be their first initial, first 3 letters of their last name, and the last 4 digits of their student number (with no spaces). I don't know how to concatenate the first 3 letters of a string or last 4 digits of a number. Can somebody help please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner user_info = new Scanner(System.in);

        String first_name;
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        first_name = user_info.next();

        String last_name;
        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        last_name = user_info.next();

        String student_number;
        System.out.print("Enter your student number: ");
        student_number = user_info.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: use subString method , here is a start http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/string-java-basics/substring-java-example/

Comment: Show proof of research, what have you tried, where else have you looked?

Answer (score 2):

first initial:

```
first_name.substring(0, 1)
```

first 3 letters of their last name:

```
 last_name.substring(0, 3)
```

last 4 digits of their student number:

```
student_number.substring(student_number.length()-4, student_number.length())
```

Comment: Just one problem: `last_name.substring(0, 2)` should be `last_name.substring(0, 3)`. Remember last index is exclusive.

Comment: Good call. Done. @dudeprgm